# My computer often shutting down

Tags: windows-7, crash, shutdown

I have no idea why my computer keep shutting down.

I'm using `windows 7` 64 bit edition.   I'm having this problem for more than a week.

Especially my computer shutting down after 10 minutes when watching videos in vlc player.

My memory dump file also not created at all. I enabled `small memory dump(256 kb)` in this location `%SystemRoot%\Minidump`. But memory dump file not created so far.

Can anyone give me some solution to create memory dump file?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 - 64 Computer shuts off unexpectedly](http://superuser.com/questions/143539/windows-7-64-computer-shuts-off-unexpectedly)

Comment: Just a guess, but it sounds as if it could be a problem of over-heating.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't get anything written to the disk, I would guess it's related to that. I myself experienced similar crashes on S2k8R2 recently, where the computer would stop doing anything for a minute or so before halting, particularly during heavy disk throughput like streaming a video. The problem in that case turned out to be a damaged SATA cable, but I guess a damaged disk or SATA controller are equally possible.

Try to check what the latest entry in the system log (or system event log? I'm not currently on a windows system, can't check.) before the reboot is, if there is nothing it's probably a similar problem. You could also disable automatic restart, so you might get a bluescreen explaining what caused the shutdown.

Finally, to make sure it is a disk related problem, you could try stress-testing the drive. I'm sure there are a lot of windows based benchmark tools for this, but I usually just boot a linux live disk and `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=1M` and watch the system log for errors. If this provokes errors or hanging, you can be quite sure the problem is related to your disk.

Answer (score 0):

"Random shut down" is often caused by overheating (bad fans, old termal paste on the CPU, airflow to the machine blocked, ...).

Comment: some suggestions on how to check it and what to do would be helpfull